# Extracting words starting with specific characters from a file, line by line, in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file

I'll start by saying I'm brand new to Perl and regex and I have never been best buddies.

My problem is, I have a text file full of lines. Each line contains many 'words'. These words can contain letters, numbers, -, =, etc. Pretty much everything except white space. Each words is separated by white space.

In every line there is one word that starts with three unique characters, 'mc='. So the word could be 'mc=abcde123', 'mc=12345hij', 'mc=blah'... you get my drift. I want to extract this word from each line and insert them into a new text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

my $input = 'input.txt';
my $output = 'output.txt';

open (FILE, "<", $input) or die "Can not open $input $!";
open my $out, '>' $output or die "Can not open $output $!";

while (<FILE>){
    /(\s+mc=\/*S)/g;
    print $out $_;
}
```

Not sure how much use any of this code will be to you. I'm well aware the regex is wrong- this just prints the entire content of input.txt into output.txt. Eventually I will be extracting additional values so If anyone could find it in their heart to help this poor, young, ignorant programmer out, I would be more than grateful!

Comment: `print $out "$1\n" if /\b(mc=\S*)/;`

Comment: You probably already have this (should be getting a syntax err), but you're also missing a comma...`open my $out,'>',$output or die "Can not open $output $!";

Comment: @mpapec That will match `fake-mc=123`.

Comment: @mpapec I assumed he wanted to match words that begin with `mc=`?

Comment: @TLP it depends on his particular input

Comment: @mpapec He says each line contains `one word that starts with three unique characters, 'mc='`. And that the word contains anything except whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you want to match is a string of non-whitespace that begins with `mc=`, which is preceded by either start of string or whitespace. So the regex you want would be

```
/(?<!\S)(mc=\S*)/g
```

Using the negative lookbehind assertion `(?<!\S)` is a way to assert that we do not have non-whitespace before our keyword. We cannot use `(?<=\s|^)` (match whitespace or beginning of string) because lookbehind assertions cannot be variable length, so this is a workaround.

You can use for example:

```
perl -nle 'print for /(?<!\S)(mc=\S*)/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

A one-liner which will print the matched strings on a new line for each word, and using shell redirection (*nix shell) we print the words to a new file. This will replace your entire script.

You can also use the following to patch your own code:

```
print $out $_ for /(?<!\S)(mc=\S*)/g;
```

But making the file names hard coded is unnecessary, I feel, especially when perl has such nice predefined features to use in this case.

Comment: @mpapec I always think the `/x` modifier makes things look strange.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Not only have you answered my question, but you've actually explained it in a way that makes sense to my tired and confused brain. Would you care to write a textbook on the subject, per chance?

Comment: You're welcome. Too limited subject for a book, surely, but I'm glad it helped.

Comment: There is already a [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do "Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Edition") about writing regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

my $input = 'input.txt';
my $output = 'output.txt';

open (FILE, "<", $input) or die "Can not open $input $!";
open my $out, '>' $output or die "Can not open $output $!";

while (<FILE>){
    my @arr = /(?: ^|\s )(mc=\S*)/xg or next;
    print $out "$_\n" for @arr;
}
```

Comment: This will match `abcmc=` as well, in fact any string which contains `mc=` because `\s*` also matches the empty string.

Comment: @mpapec With the amount of editing you've done on this question, you might as well have written your own answer. :)

Comment: Thanks folks, you've explained the solution brilliantly!